# GNU Make - How to specify a default recipe for all phony rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project with a bunch of phony Makefile rules that depend on each other, all sharing the same basic recipe. (This Makefile is used more for mapping dependencies than for producing build artifacts.) The Makefile looks something like this:

```
.PHONY: foo bar baz qux
foo:
    @echo $@
bar: foo
    @echo $@
baz: foo
    @echo $@
qux: bar baz
    @echo $@
```

In actuality, the Makefile defines dozens of rules, so it has become quite verbose. Instead of explicitly specifying the same recipe for each rule, I'd like to follow the DRY principle and define a default recipe for all the targets, resulting in a Makefile like this:

```
.PHONY: foo bar baz qux
foo:
bar: foo
baz: foo
qux: bar baz
```

***The part I'm missing is how to define that default recipe.*** One "workaround" I've found is to use a macro-based approach, but it ends up with a lot of duplicate code and makes the rules far less readable:

```
define defrule
.PHONY: $1
$1: $2
    @echo $$@
endef

$(eval $(call defrule,foo))
$(eval $(call defrule,bar,foo))
$(eval $(call defrule,baz,foo))
$(eval $(call defrule,qux,bar baz))
```

I'm wondering if maybe a [match-anything rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules) could help, although I haven't had any success with that. Also note that I don't care about recipes running multiple times (when targeting `qux`, the `foo` rule gets run twice, and that's fine for my use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to follow the DRY principle and define a default recipe for all the targets

If you want to specify that multiple targets should be built according to the same recipe then you just name them all as targets of the same rule:

```
foo bar baz qux:
    @echo $@
```

That specifies that *each* target can be built by running the rule's recipe, not that *all* of them are built by a single run of the recipe, which I think is precisely what you want.  The `$@` correctly reflects the target being built on any execution of the recipe.

You can declare their dependencies with separate, dependency-only rules:

```
bar: foo
baz: foo
qux: bar baz
```

.  And of course, you can still declare them .PHONY:

```
.PHONY: foo bar baz qux
```

Comment: Perfect! Despite having seen that construct before in the manual, this is the first time it was ever applicable to me.